What issurim are involved in putting a pin through material on Shabbos?
The question is about putting a pin through material on Shabbos for example to pin on a brooch onto a garment. I think there are 3 situations:
1] the material is non-woven; putting in the pin will remove material where the pin goes in.
2] the material is tight woven;  putting in the pin will disturb the weave permanently.
3] the material is loosely woven; the pin can be inserted in the spaces in the weave.
I would assume that [1] is a rabbinic issur of כל המקללין פטורים. I imagine [3] is allowed. I don't know about [2].
What issurim are involved in putting a pin through material on Shabbos?
